# Pass arguments through self in class instance while multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, multiprocessing, fork

It seems to work, but is it safe to use `self` after forking? Or should I always pass arguments to the subprocess as function parameters through `args`?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class C():

    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'bla'
        p = mp.Process(target=self.worker, args=[])
        #p = mp.Process(target=self.worker, args=(self.v,))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def worker(self):
        print(self.v)

    #def worker(self, v):
        #print(v)

c = C()

# prints 'bla'
```

To be more specific, I want to pass manager.Queue() objects, not sure, if it makes a difference.

If this was a simple C fork(), since the whole process is copied identically - except for the pid -, `self` would be the same. But Python multiprocessing may be doing something I am not aware of, or there may be a warning somewhere like "don't use it like this, this may change in the future". I did not find anything addressing specifically this question.

My actual worries is that arguments passed in `args`, especially if they are associated with the multiprocessing module may be transformed around fork() to avoid whatever problems.

Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything other than the *fork* start method, both the target and the arguments are sent to the worker processes using [pickling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), when `Process.start()` is called. For the *fork* method, the child process is forked at the same point, so when `Process.start()` is called.

So when you don't use the *fork* start method, what you need to worry about is if your data can be pickled. When that is the case then there is no reason to avoid using a class instance and `self`; the whole instance is pickled as `self.target` is a method that includes a reference to the instance:

```
>>> class C:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.v = 'bla'
...     def worker(self):
...         print(self.v)
...
>>> c = C()
>>> data = pickle.dumps(c.worker)
>>> pickletools.dis(data)
    0: \x80 PROTO      4
    2: \x95 FRAME      71
   11: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'builtins'
   21: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 0)
   22: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'getattr'
   31: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 1)
   32: \x93 STACK_GLOBAL
   33: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 2)
   34: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE '__main__'
   44: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 3)
   45: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'C'
   48: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 4)
   49: \x93 STACK_GLOBAL
   50: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 5)
   51: )    EMPTY_TUPLE
   52: \x81 NEWOBJ
   53: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 6)
   54: }    EMPTY_DICT
   55: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 7)
   56: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'v'
   59: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 8)
   60: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'bla'
   65: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 9)
   66: s    SETITEM
   67: b    BUILD
   68: \x8c SHORT_BINUNICODE 'worker'
   76: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 10)
   77: \x86 TUPLE2
   78: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 11)
   79: R    REDUCE
   80: \x94 MEMOIZE    (as 12)
   81: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 4
```

In the above stream you can clearly see `v`, `'blah'` and `worker` named.

If you do use the *fork* start method, then the child process simply has full access to everything that was in memory in the parent process; `self` is still referencing the same object you had before forking. Your OS takes care of the details there, such as ensuring that file descriptors are independent, and that the child process gets a copy of the memory blocks that are being altered.

Either way, further changes you make to the instance won't be visible to the parent process, unless you explicitly use [data structures designed to be shared](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: Just that I understand correctly: `target==self.worker` AND `self.worker` has `self.worker.reference_to_self` THUS when `target` is sent over to the new process, it will have access to the same attributes as before, which includes `target.reference_to_self==self.worker.reference_to_self`

Comment: @ZoltanK.: the object returned by the expression `self.worker` is a *bound method object*. That object has a reference to the instance, that''s how methods get the instance passed in when called. You can see this yourself, try `self.worker.__self__`. To send that method to a new process, it is pickled, and pickling records everything about the method object that's needed to recreate it on the other side, including the instance attribute values. So yes, you understand it correctly. :-)